# When implementing 'Export as Excel' type of feature, what's the best practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net, .net, web

I hope you are doing well!

We are trying to implement the 'Export as Excel' feature in some tables in our website and here is our situation.

The data returns as array of objects that look like this:

```
[
{
name: {firstName: 'Robert', lastName:'Smith'},
age: 10,
job: 'Developer',
maritalStatus:'Single',
partner: null
},...
]
```

and we loop through the array to display the values.

Now we found 2 ways to do it:

1. Create the Excel file in the backend (.NET), fill it and send it to the frontend where the file is downloaded.
2. Create the file and download it from the frontend (React JS).

Creating the file from the frontend we will have to loop through 2 array, one holding the data like the one above and the other holding the {"Key":"Value"} format we want to format it in.

Which approach is better and more optimal?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Generating files usually is easier done in the backend. It‘s a typical backend task as it processes information and offers it in a different format. Whenever feasible, I‘d opt for the backend.

Yes, it‘s doable in the UI, but then you have different browsers to consider and it feels like forcing something on the frontend, that is not its job ;)

Comment: This makes a lot of sense! Alright Thank You!